# count lines in with 2 words

Tags: grep

I have a text file with many lines like -

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox did not jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox may jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox may not jumps over the lazy dog
anything can happen
nothing can happen
```

I want to get the count of occurrences in lines where both 'fox' and 'jumps' comes.

Tried `grep -ci "$word1|word2' $file`
but this is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe `grep` to `grep`, only doing the count on the second instance of `grep` like so:

```
grep -i fox $file | grep -ci brown
```

Alternatively you can use `egrep` which is the same as `grep -E`, and use a regular expression:

```
egrep -ci 'fox.*brown|brown.*fox' $file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo -e "fox:$(grep -c fox aaa)\njumps:$(grep -c jumps aaa)"
```

aaa : your file name

and your command wrong

```
grep -ci "fox\|jumpsa" aaa
```